# Deploy libgdx to html5 on android studio

Tags: java, html, gwt, android-studio, libgdx

I created a game using libgdx with android studio (Intellij) and I would like to deploy it as a html5 code.

Can someone please help me doing this?

I saw that when using eclipse it's simply right clicking on the html package, and selecting "Google -> GWT Compile" but i can't find anything like that in android studio (intellij.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a couple ways to go about this.

1) In the *Gradle* window, under All Tasks, find the `:html` subproject, then run its `dist` task.

2) In the *Terminal* window, type `gradlew html:dist` and press enter.

Either of these methods will result in a `dist` directory within the `html/build` directory, which will contain the files you will need to deploy.

Comment: If like me you're not sure where the Gradle window is, select View > Tool Windows > Gradle (Android Studio 1.1.0).